# Code shows "Internal Server Error" and does not redirect me to the correct website

Tags: php, html, forms

Hey guys so i have this error for this particular code only and this is the error. all my other website codes work except for doEditAccount.php which gives me this error.

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.2.0 Server at localhost Port 80

This below is my code:
Account.php :

```
//User can choose to edit or delete their account here
session_start();
include_once("linkConnection.php");
include_once("navbar.php");
include_once("session.php");



if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
    $userId=$_SESSION['userId'];


    $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = $userId";
    $Result=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,$query));

    echo " <br><b>Username</b> : ".$_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<br><b>Password</b> : ".$Result['password'];
    echo "<br><b>Name</b> : ".$Result['name'];
    echo "<br><b>Date of Birth</b> : " .$Result['dob'];
    echo "<br><b>Email</b> : " .$Result['email'];
    
    
    ?>
    

<form action="editAccount.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit Account" name="edit1"/>
</form>
<br>
<form action="deleteAccount.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Account"/>
</form>
<br><br>
<?php
}
else{
    echo "Please Login to View Account Information.";
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Account Customization</h3>
        <?php
        $Points_needed=100-$Result['points'];
     
        
            ?>
    <p>Current Level : <?php echo $Result['level']?> (You need <?php echo $Points_needed?> more points to level up!)</p>
<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:<?php echo $Result['points']?>%"><?php echo $Result['points']?></div>
</div>

    
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])){?>
    <form action="doEditAccount.php" method="post">
                <br/><br/>
                                <div class="level-container">
                                    <label>Level 1 :</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    
                                <input type="radio" name="color" value="lightgrey" />Light Grey
                                <input type="radio" name="color" value="lightyellow"/>Light Yellow
                                <input type="radio" name="color" value="beige"/>Beige
                                <input type="radio" name="color" value="lightpink"/>Light Pink
                                <input type="radio" name="color" value="darkseagreen"/>Dark Sea Green
                                <input type="radio" name="color" value="lightblue"/>Light Blue
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                
                                
                                ?>
                                
    <?php
                                if ($Result['level']>=5){ ?>
                                   
                                     <div class="level-container">
                                         <label>Level 5 :</label>
                                         <br>
                                         <br>
                                     <input type="radio" name="lv5BG" value="background.jpg" />Mystical Background
                                     <input type="radio" name="lv5BG" value="hellokitty.jpg" />Hello Kitty Background
                                     <input type="radio" name="lv5BG" value="yellow.jpg" />Flowery Background
                                     </div>
                                <?php
                                }else{
                                    ?>
                                <div class="level-container">
                                         <label>Level 5 :</label>
                                         <br>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="radio" name="lv5BG" value="background.jpg" disabled/>Mystical Background
                                         <input type="radio" name="lv5BG" value="hellokitty.jpg" disabled/>Hello Kitty Background
                                         <input type="radio" name="lv5BG" value="yellow.jpg" disabled/>Flowery Background
                                     </div>
                                        <?php
                                }
                                if ($Result['level']>=10){?>
                                     <div class="level-container">
                                         <label>Level 10 :</label>
                                         <br><br>
                                     <input type="radio" name="lv10BG" value="lv10 - movable rainbow.gif" />Movable rainbow gif
                                     <input type="radio" name="lv10BG" value="lv10 - lightbugs.gif" />Mystical Movable Firebugs
                                     </div>
                                     <?php
                                }else{?>
                                    <div class="level-container">
                                         <label>Level 10 :</label>
                                         <br><br>
                                         <input type="radio" name="lv10BG" value="lv10 - movable rainbow.gif" disabled/>Movable rainbow gif
                                         <input type="radio" name="lv10BG" value="lv10 - lightbugs.gif" disabled/>Mystical Movable Firebugs
                                     </div>
                                <?php
                                }
                ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Confirm Change" name="edit2"/>
            </form>
            <?php
    }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Account.php form input goes to doEditAccount.php , and this is the code below.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include_once("linkConnection.php");
include_once("navbar.php");
include_once("session.php");



if(isset($_POST['edit1'])){
    
}else{
    
}
// $_SESSION['Cmsg'] = Customization Message
if (isset($_POST['edit2'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
        $plaincolor = $_POST['color'];
        setcookie("lv5BG", "", time() - 3600); // Remove lv5BG cookie if it exists
        setcookie("lv10BG", "", time() - 3600); // Remove lv10BG cookie if it exists
        setcookie("plaincolor", $plaincolor, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);
        $_SESSION['Cmsg'] = "You have successfully changed background to $plaincolor.";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['lv5BG'])) {
        $lv5BG = $_POST['lv5BG'];
        setcookie("plaincolor", "", time() - 3600); // Remove plaincolor cookie if it exists
        setcookie("lv10BG", "", time() - 3600); // Remove lv10BG cookie if it exists
        setcookie("lv5BG", $lv5BG, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);
        $_SESSION['Cmsg'] = "You have successfully changed background to $lv5BG.";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['lv10BG'])) {
        $lv10BG = $_POST['lv10BG'];
        setcookie("plaincolor", "", time() - 3600); // Remove plaincolor cookie if it exists
        setcookie("lv5BG", "", time() - 3600); // Remove lv5BG cookie if it exists
        setcookie("lv10BG", $lv10BG, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You have successfully changed background to $lv10BG.";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['Cmsg'] = "You have submitted nothing. No change to customizations.";
    }
    header('Location : Login.php');
}

    ?>
```

Login.php:

```
 <?php 
 session_start();

include_once("navbar.php");
include_once("session.php");


$backgroundStyle = "";
if (isset($_COOKIE['plaincolor'])) {
    $backgroundStyle = "background-color: " . $_COOKIE['plaincolor'] . ";";
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['lv5BG'])) {
    $backgroundStyle = "background-image: url(images/".$_COOKIE['lv5BG'].")";

}elseif (isset($_COOKIE['lv10BG'])) {
    $backgroundStyle = "background-image: url(images/".$_COOKIE['lv10BG'].")";
    echo $_COOKIE['lv10BG'];
}

echo $backgroundStyle;
?>





<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         
    </head>
    <body style="<?php echo $backgroundStyle?>; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
       
        
         
        <!--
        form
        -->
         <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
                ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <h5><?php echo $_SESSION['msg'];?></h5>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
            ?>
       <form name="Login" method="post" action="doLogin.php" class="ReviewEdit">
            <h1>Login Page :</h1>
            <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){?>
            Your Username: <br>
            <input style="border:2px solid black;" id="idName" type="text" name="Uname" placeholder="Enter your username" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['username']?>"/>
            
            <br><br>
           <?php
            }else{?>
            Your Username: <br>
            <input style="border:2px solid black;" id="idName" type="text" name="Uname" placeholder="Enter your username" />
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            Your Password: <br>
            <input style="border:2px solid black;" id="idEmail" type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Enter your password"/>
            <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Remember me" name="Remember">Remember Me
            <a href="forget-password.php">Forget Password</a>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            <br><br>       
            
</form>
        
         <h5 class="notImportant forlogin"> Not a member yet? Register <a href="Register.php" style="color: darkslategray">here</a> </h5>


    </body>
</html>
```

and then i redirect to Login.php , to let users see their updated background .Problem is when i click on the "Confirm Change" button , it gives me tnhat error as previously said on the website doEditAccount.php , other than this my other websites all work. Any idea whats the problem?

thought it was the redirecting's problem so i tried to remove the header("Location:Login.php") but same issue remained. This website worked previously and all of a sudden when i tried to run it again it just had this error and wouldn't budge

Comment: Can you please edit your question? It clearly has some readability problems. When you write, or edit, a question you can preview the result underneath the input fields.

Comment: how do i edit bruh

Comment: Please can you share the relevant parts of doEditAccount.php?

Comment: Ah, you found it! 

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code, apart from the missing `<?php` at the beginning of the scripts, but I think those are not actually missing. The best advice now is to [check the PHP error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel).

Answer (score 1):

try to remove space after Location in `header('Location : Login.php');` to `header('Location: Login.php');` and add exit under function header to prevent any further code execution after the redirect header is sent, which is considered a good practice when using header() for redirects

Like this :

```
header('Location: Login.php');
exit;
```

Comment: This is indeed a problem. The error log should contains something like: _"Response header name 'Location ' contains invalid characters, aborting request"_.

Comment: thank you @Rahmat Hidayat! i just tried out and it appears the space was actually the problem..

Comment: @q1an.qian Nice, but now you know how to find the problem yourself next time.

Comment: ok @q1an.qian happi coding :)